# I cant access SQL Server on Remote Desktop (SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tags: sql-server, azure, rdp, windows-firewall

I moved my project to another hosting company. However, in my remote desktop project, I tried updating the database information via app.config, but it does not see the database.

**When deleting the model and adding it again, it gives the following error;**

Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance Specified)"

**I tried this;** I allowed the **'1433'** port, which is the SQL port on the firewall side. **(IN RDP)**

**I tried this;** I allowed the UDP port **'1434'** on the firewall side. **(IN RDP)**

**I tried this;** Firewall shut down I tried to connect **(IN RDP)**

**I tried this;** I tried to allow 1433 on the **Azure side**, but it was already allowed.

Since SQL Server is not installed on my remote server, I cannot see the **Services - SQL Server** side and **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, but if the SQL service was closed, my previous hosting company would give the same error while connecting to the database.

When I take my project from the remote server and try it on my own computer, I can access the database without any problems. But I cannot access it on the remote server.

My hosting company say we don't need any permission. I don't know what to do anymore I really need help

Comment: Wait, are you trying to access the instance on your local machine from the remote instance..?

Comment: What exact do you have on this remote desktop ? Does your application resides there and you need to make a connection to an SQL Server on a hosting site ? Or what exact are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to connect to the hosting database from my project located on the remote desktop @Larnu

Comment: I have an API project on remote desktop and I put the .exe file of this API project in windows services so the API is constantly running in the background. @GuidoG

Comment: Do you use "windows security" or "username/password" in your connectionstring ? I asume that the service will run under local system account, which might not have permission to login to the sql server. If that is the case then use "username/password" in your connection string

Comment: yes i use   <add name="xxx" connectionString="metadata=xx;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xx\MSSQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=xxx;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> @GuidoG

Comment: `data source=xx\MSSQLSERVER2014` ? xx is what ? Ip ?

Comment: xx is example. it is database ip @JasonPan